# Drupal 7 and CKEditor edit via js

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, wysiwyg, users

I used ckeditor without Drupal.

There I can call this to configure it in js file:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'myEditor', {
        stylesSet: [
        { name: 'header', element: 'p', attributes: { class : 'head' } }
        ]
    });
```

But in drupal CKEDITOR is undefined. I have tried Drupal.settings.ckeditor, but still undefined. Is some way how to enable it?

I need to create specific styles for one Content type field in admin and I need to do it in my module without CMS. Is some way how to achieve it?

Thank you